# Swift UI scrollTo proper anchor parameter

Tags: swift, scroll, swiftui, anchor

I'm working with scrollTo in a Swift UI project. Here's a visual of an example I've been using to understand the logic.

[image]

The example texts range from 0 to 99, with 99 being the last one and the one I am scrolling to. Note that the frame of example 99 extends below the bottom edge of the screen. How do I anchor the view such that the entire frame of 99 is visible? I'm guessing that this has to do with scrollTo's anchor parameter, but all the anchor values I've tried haven't seemed to do anything.

Here's my code:

```js
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Feed: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { value in
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    Text("Example \(i)")
                        .font(.title)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .id(i)
                }
                .onAppear() {
                    value.scrollTo(99)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Some people in the comments pointed out that the Simulator renders the right output even if the Preview does not. Here is what the code looks like in the Simulator, with a black border added to highlight the frame:

[image]

Note that the frames don't extend past the bottom of the screen anymore.

Comment: Every thing working just fine! maybe your preview get messed up! try on simulator.

Comment: I don't see this issue in previews or the simulator. Also, in your image I don't see any space between the blue squares from the default padding. Is this code exactly what is showing in the preview?

Comment: That image is the preview rendered by the exact code pasted. But I tried it in the Simulator and the issue is now gone...

Comment: @JohnSorensen Previews can be a bit weird sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `scrollTo` from within `withAnimation` when using `onAppear`, otherwise scrolling behavior is very inconsistent.

Other than that, I always get good results with the `.center` anchor.

So in your case:

```
.onAppear() {
    withAnimation {
        value.scrollTo(99, anchor: .center)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I want an animation, though, as I want to simply start the stack at the bottom rather than give the impression of the stack going to the bottom. If that makes sense.

Comment: Adding ```withAnimation``` does seem to make it a little bit more consistent, but it seems it's still kinda not consistent. possibly a bug? (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688230?page=2). I added a ```DispatchQueue.main.async``` and possibly better. Needs more testing.. somehow it's still incosistent